# Verify user email without redirecting to RESTFUL API in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I have an http client what consumes an restful api both of them on Laravel, I need to verify the email of the user without redirect to the API.

I already have an EmailVerifyNotification in my resftul api exactly equal to the given for Laravel, but I can't custom the URL.

The situation is that the user requests to forward the mail to verify it from the http client to the api, the api processes the request, creates and sends the mail but sends it in relation to the path defined in the api, in this case:

```
// RESTFUL API routes/api.php
Route::name('verification.verify')->get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'User\UserController@verify');
```

**Example:**

By clicking a button the user on the client side call a controller what do an http request to the api:

```
// this call a restful api route from the http client
// restulapi.com/email/resend
return $this->makeRequest('GET', "email/resend");
```

on the restful api I have a controller what call a notification equal to the given for Laravel, but that use a route verification.verify what I have to define on the routes of the api:

```
// RESTFUL API App/Notifications/VerifyEmailNotification
protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
{
    return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verification.verify', <----- I need to change this
        Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
        [
            'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
            'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
        ]
    );
}

// 
// RESTFUL API routes/api.php
// the button to verify the email call this route -> restfulapi.com/email/verify/{id}/{hash}
// but i need -> httpclient.com/email/verify/{id}/{hash}
Route::name('verification.verify')->get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'User\UserController@verify');
```

The point its verify the user email without move from the http client.

Comment: you could extend that notification and override `verificationUrl` and on the User model or what ever the notification is being sent to you can override `sendEmailVerificationNotification` to send the notification you want (the same notification but customizing the url for the verification url) ... if you had to

Comment: I updated my question maybe i don't explain good, I would like to keep cue consistency of the functions of Laravel, but if there is no other way, it's okay